# WSO2 API Manager in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to deploy API Manager and Enterprise Integrator using Docker Compose. This is deployed using a cloud server.

Everything works locally when using localhost as the host but when I deploy it on a using a cloud server, I cannot access the API Manager using the public IP of the server. The Enterprise Integrator works though. I've modified some configuration parameters as shown below but the problem persists:

```
 <APIStore>
<!--GroupingExtractor>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.DefaultGroupIDExtractorImpl</GroupingExtractor-->
    <!--This property is used to indicate how we do user name comparision for token generation https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2225-->
    <CompareCaseInsensitively>true</CompareCaseInsensitively>
    <DisplayURL>false</DisplayURL>
    <URL>https://<PUBLIC IP HERE>:${mgt.transport.https.port}/store</URL>

    <!-- Server URL of the API Store. -->
    <ServerURL>https://<PUBLIC IP HERE>:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
```

I've also whitelisted the said public IP:

```
"whiteListedHostNames" : ["localhost","PUBLIC IP HERE"]
```

Comment: you can't access anything? store? publisher? any errors in the log?

Comment: Nothing. No errors as well.

Comment: what is the status code you get when you send a get to `/store`?

Comment: curl -v https://<PUBLIC IP>:9453/store
*   Trying <PUBLIC IP>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to <PUBLIC IP> port 9453 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to <PUBLIC IP> port 9453: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <PUBLIC IP> port 9453: Operation timed out

Comment: try this and send me the results.
`telnet <public_ip> 9453`

Comment: Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to x.x.x.x.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: so it's not a connectivity issue. please check http access logs of the server.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure which log file I can find that. This one? ~/wso2am-2.6.0/repository/logs/http_access_2019-09-10.log.

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Do you see your requests in it?

Comment: Okay, this is embarrassing. Apparently the particular network I was on was blocking port 9453. Just that one so it didn't cross my mind since 9443 was working quite well. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: hmm that's what I wanted to check with the telnet command. I wonder how it worked. Anyway, glad it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile please check the [reference](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Changing+the+Hostname).

Comment: Hi @LW1! Thanks! Unfortunately I already tried that and it didn't work.